# What's the state-of-the-art tool for ​ASR (automatic speech recognition) Error Detection?

Tags: software, speech-recognition, classifiers, errors

ASR Error Detection = automatically detect erroneous words in ASR output.

The survey {1} was published 4 years ago. {2} didn't release their implementation.

---

References:

- {1} Errattahi, Rahhal, Asmaa El Hannani, and Hassan Ouahmane. "Automatic speech recognition errors detection and correction: A review." Procedia Computer Science 128 (2018): 32-37. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.procs.2018.03.005
- {2} Meripo, Nimshi Venkat, and Sandeep Konam. "ASR Error Detection via Audio-Transcript entailment." Interspeech 2022. https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.10849

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any pointer is welcome.